# How to prevent adding another SPAN element?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with a to-do app. I want to cross out a LI element and add a span with an x sign. It's easy by toggling class. However, when I "untoggle" the class by clicking again. The "x" remains and when I click on the item again the "x" is duplicated. How can I prevent adding another "x" or make the "x" disappear when the items is "untoggled".

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
const input = document.querySelector("input[name='input-item'");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const allItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
  allItems[i].addEventListener("click", myList);
}

function myList() {
  let temp = this.classList.toggle("red");
  if (temp) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "&times;";
    span.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentElement.remove();
    });
    this.appendChild(span);
  } else if (this.classList.contains("red")) {
    this.getElementByTagName("span").remove();
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}

span {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 0.3rem;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="input-item" placeholder="Enter a new item" /><button id="add">Add Item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementByTagName()` is misspelled and therefore should be displaying an error in your dev tools console. In addition -  when spelled correctly it does not return a single element and the collection  does not have a remove method. Try using `querySelector('span')`  and using a classname on the span will make it even more specific

Comment: Thanks David Thomas. I've missed that. The correct code should be: this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].remove();